# matlab - print subarray of two dimensional array

Tags: matlab

hi let's assume i have the following in matlab

```
             h = [0,0,0,1;
                  1,1,1,1];
```

now how can i print all the values of the first subarray, i.e. 0,0,0,1

or for example the second subarray 1,1,1,1. thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access just the first row of your matrix by doing

```
   firstRow = h(1,:)
```

Similarly, you could access just the third column by

```
   thirdColumn = h(:,3)
```

I suggest you look into the MATLAB help under ["Matrix Indexing"](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html) as this is really basic stuff (and there's a lot of other nifty things you can do to access a subset of a matrix)

For printing, you can omit the final `;`, or look into functions `display` and `fprintf`.